# Unzip artifacts with different name

Tags: go

I have a program in which I need to copy the folder contents (from `folder1`) to a new folder (`folder2`) in the same dir level (path).
Since I cannot give the same name I use tmpFolder name (for `folder2`).
When I finish to do all the logic I need zip the copied folder 
and I give the zip the name `folder1.zip`
The problem is that when I extract the `folder1.zip`
I see `folder2`.

I want it to be `folder1` after the zip.

Is there some trick I can use to do it?

In addition, I know that I can copy to folder2 in different level (path) but I want to avoid it if possible since
the copy can be very expensive when working on big folder contents.

I use this code to zip the folder:

```
func Zipit(source, target string) error {
    zipfile, err := os.Create(target)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer zipfile.Close()

    archive := zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
    defer archive.Close()

    info, err := os.Stat(source)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    var baseDir string
    if info.IsDir() {
        baseDir = filepath.Base(source)
    }

    filepath.Walk(source, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if baseDir != "" {
            header.Name = filepath.Join(baseDir, strings.TrimPrefix(path, source))
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            header.Name += "/"
        } else {
            header.Method = zip.Deflate
        }

        writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
        return err
    })

    return err
}
```

Comment: You can change `header.Name` to be whatever you want, this is the name of the file inside the archive. This is set to the filename in `zip.FileInfoHeader(info)`.

Comment: @Marc - can you please write where it should be ? is it like this   `name := info.Name("test")

  header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(name)` ?

Comment: You want to keep `FileInfoHeader` as it also sets other fields (timestamp, size, etc..). But parts of your code already change `header.Name`. You just need to replace `folder2` in the path with `folder1`. Or even easier: change `baseDir` to `folder1` before `filepath.Walk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names of files and directories in zip archives come from the [zip.FileHeader](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#FileHeader).

Your code already initializes the header from the [os.FileInfo](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo). This is important as it populates metadata such as timestamps and uncompressed size.

Furthermore, your code seems to be doing the following:

If invoked with:

```
Zipit("/path/to/folder2/", "/path/to/folder1.zip")
```

Before traversing the directory tree, it computes the base directory:

```
baseDir = filepath.Base(source)
// baseDir is "folder2"
```

Then for each file, the path inside the archive is set to:

```
header.Name = filepath.Join(baseDir, strings.TrimPrefix(path, source))
```

This turns a filename such as `/path/to/folder2/otherdir/myfile` into `folder2/otherdir/myfile`.

If you want to change the directory name stored inside the archive, you just need to change `baseDir` to the desired name.

I would recommend the following solution:

Change the function signature to:

```
func Zipit(source, target, newBaseName string) error {
```

Change the basedir to:

```
if newBaseName != "" {
    baseDir = newBaseName
else if info.IsDir() {
    baseDir = filepath.Base(source)
}
```

Then call your function with:

```
Zipit("/path/to/folder2/", "/path/to/folder1.zip", "folder1")
```

This should result in an archive that extracts into `folder1/`.

Comment: Thanks marc , one last thing is that sometime I need to use the `zipit` method with 2 paramters and sometimes with 3 like you did, how would you do it ?

Comment: You wouldn't, Go does not allow multiple function signatures. You can either the proposal above which keeps the old behavior is `newBaseName` is empty, or you can create a helper function.

Comment: please see if you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751091/go-zip-content-inside-folder-without-the-root-folder