# Zip content inside folder without the root folder

Tags: go

I want to zip some directory inside content into zip file

e.g. assume i’ve this directory structure

```
dir1
  file1.html
  file2.go
```

Now I want to zip it to `dir1.zip` which is working

when I extract it I got the same structure...
I want to zip the **content inside** that when I unzip it I get the files inside  without the `dir1' folder as root after extracting it

```
file1.html
file2.go
```

I try to play with the path’s with this code and it doesn’t work,
Any idea what I miss here ?

i've tryied

```
func Zipit(source, target string) error {
    zipfile, err := os.Create(target)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer zipfile.Close()

    archive := zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
    defer archive.Close()

    info, err := os.Stat(source)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    var baseDir string
    if info.IsDir() {
        baseDir = filepath.Base(source)
    }

    filepath.Walk(source, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if baseDir != "" {
            header.Name = filepath.Join(baseDir, strings.TrimPrefix(path, source))
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            header.Name += "/"
        } else {
            header.Method = zip.Deflate
        }

        writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
        return err
    })

    return err
}



dir.Zipit("path/dir1" +"/", "test"+".zip")
```

Or maybe there is simpler way in GO to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are calling your function as follows:

```
Zipit("dir1/", "dir1.zip")
```

All you need to do is remove the `baseDir` that is being added to the filename inside the archive.

You currently have the following code:

```
if baseDir != "" {
        header.Name = filepath.Join(baseDir, strings.TrimPrefix(path, source))
}
```

`baseDir` here is `dir1`.

Simply omit the `baseDir` (but to keep trimming the prefix):

```
header.Name = strings.TrimPrefix(path, source)
```

This is very similar to [Unzip artifacts with different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732412/unzip-artifacts-with-different-name) where all you need to do is modify `header.Name` as you see fit. It sounds like you need to examine the various `filepath` functions to see how they can help you.

Comment: Btw should I keep the if statement ?

Comment: No need since it's not being used. That said, I recommend you take the time to understand what this code does if you want to make it do something different.

Comment: header.Name = filepath.Base(path)
is probably a better choice, as you will otherwise wind up with an extra slash.